# Automata - Regular Expression

Tags: regex, automation, regular-language

I've been trying to make a regular expression from the below:

L = {01, 0011, 000111, 00001111, 0000011111, 000000111111, ...}

but I just could not figure it out. The first thing that came to my mind was

0(0)^* 1(1)^*

Is there an app where I could test it out?

If this can't be done through Regular Expression, can an NFA or DFA be done?

but I'm not sure if that is the answer to the language. Could some good Samaritan kindly help me with this? Appreciate it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cN9aL8/1

Comment: @Cyrbil +1 for regex101, but I believe the inputs must have the same number of 0 and 1, i.e. 00111 should not match.

Comment: @Cyrbil It should be `[01]+`

Comment: @hek2mgl This allows 110010100 for example.

Comment: @sp00m Probably I failed to get the question. What does `L =` stands for?

Comment: Language. :) That was what I've been told

Answer (score 4):

A [subroutine](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) may suit your needs:

```
(?<!0)(0(?1)?1)(?!1)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OzdL7kLX8WQ2GG7d)

`(?1)` means *recall the pattern captured in the first group*, i.e. between the parens. This isn't available in all regex engines though - neither is the (negative) lookbehind `(?<!...)` by the way.

The difference between `(?1)` and `\1` is that `(?1)` recalls the captured *pattern* while `\1` recalls the captured *data*.

Comment: I was striving to get the length match, this is dope !

Comment: Almost ...Please check https://regex101.com/r/cN9aL8/2 .. You can add word boundaries like this: https://regex101.com/r/cN9aL8/3 . Anyway, good answer!

Comment: Any idea on how to do this exact subroutine in Python?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about what you meant when you said that it should be regex, because it is mentioned automaton/regular expression too.

As per the automata theory :-

If you are talking about the regular expression for this formal language *(having equal number of 0's and 1's and all 0's must be followed by 1's)*, it is not a regular language. It can be proved using the pumping lemma that this language is not regular.

But, this language can be expressed as **{0<sup>i</sup>1<sup>i</sup>** | **i>0}**; i belongs to set of positive integers.